# Facebook credits API / Facebook payment API

Tags: facebook, payment, facebook-credits

Facebook has credits / payment feature, but I can't seem to find a payment API.

How does my app give out credits or receives credits from its users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook Credits is still in [beta phase](http://developers.facebook.com/credits), so I guess they are keeping it a secret for now. Facebook is looking for developers to take part in the beta program though.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation is available:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/creditsapi

but you still have to request beta access at the moment (26 Oct 2010)

Answer (score 0):

Today, we’re announcing a significant expansion in the number of developers that can be part of Facebook Credits, the virtual currency used in games and applications on Facebook. And working with our friends at PlaySpan, we plan to add more than 20 new ways for people to pay for Facebook Credits in the coming months.

[From Facebook Developers Blog](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/416)